# greatest() function returns undefined property

Tags: plugins, database, query-posts, functions, mysql

I'm using the mysql [GREATEST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function to compare two table fields and display in a loop either one with the highest integer value. The 2 fields consist of vote scores for posts: UP or DOWN.

```
function vote_results($post_id) { 
  global $wpdb; 
  $table = $wpdb->prefix . "post_votes";    
  $results = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT GREATEST (up, down) FROM $table WHERE voted_post_id = $post_id" );
  echo $results->up; //echo if highest value
  echo $results->down; //echo if highest value

}
```

Then in my loop I call the function but get `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$up` for

```
echo $results->up;
```

and the same notice for `down`. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What does `var_dump($results);` get you?

Comment: I get this, `object(stdClass)#91 (1) { ["GREATEST(up, down)"]=> string(2) "74"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use `get_var()`, not `get_row()` - [looking at the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest), MySQL's `GREATEST` just returns a single value.

`$results` will then just be the value of the greatest (be it `up` or `down`).

If you want the greatest `up` **and** the greatest `down`, use;

```
$wpdb->get_row("SELECT GREATEST(up) AS 'up', GREATEST(down) AS 'down' ...")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually want up or down not both otherwise I would use a regular query. I used `get_row()` but now I get `Trying to get property of non-object` for `echo $results->up;` and `echo $results->down;`, this using the initial `greatest()`

Comment: Yeah... so use `get_var()` instead, and the returned result will simply be the value of `GREATEST`

Comment: Ok I used `get_var()` like so `$results = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT GREATEST(up, down) FROM $table WHERE voted_post_id = $post_id" ) );` and then I use `<?php echo $results->up; ?>` and `<?php echo $results->down; ?>` to retrieve either up or down, whichever is highest. I get `Trying to get property of non-object` I don't understand why.. I already have the `$wpdb` global

Comment: maybe it's not picking up post_id ?

Comment: No, using `get_var()`, `$results` is just a value (the greatest of either up or down) - there is no `up` or `down` property, as `$results` is not an object!

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I finally get it! I just have to echo `$results` :) Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with TheDeadMedic... If you use GREATEST(), please do yourself a favor by knowing what you're doing. It returns a bigint when fed ints, and your query doesn't give the resulting column any name. So $wpdb will obviously complain when you try to access a column which is not available. :-)

I believe you're seeking this:

```
SELECT up - down as total, up, down FROM $table WHERE voted_post_id = $post_id
```

Comment: I tested `GREATEST()` in phpmyadmin and it works fine. It returns the highest values from either the up or down columns. Maybe  my question wasn't clear, sorry. I'm just having trouble with wp

Comment: also the up and down fields are bigint

Comment: Oh, I thought you were seeking the highest up minus down. If not, in that case yeah: `SELECT greatest(up, down) as highest, up, down FROM $table WHERE voted_post_id = $post_id`. Note the `as highest`

Comment: Thanks Denis!! Sorry again for not properly explaining.